# Using deprecated 'credentials' format in JSON representation error shown during Keycloak user creation

Tags: java, keycloak

Using deprecated 'credentials' format in JSON representation error shown during Keycloak user creation in 23.0.x. The error mentions CredentialRepresentation.getHashIterations() as null, but the above field is deprecated and there is no way to set the attribute.

```
2023-12-01 15:03:36,761 WARN  [org.keycloak.models.utils.RepresentationToModel] (executor-thread-8) Using deprecated 'credentials' format in JSON representation for user 'Sapil'. It will be removed in future versions
2023-12-01 15:03:36,762 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-8) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "org.keycloak.representations.idm.CredentialRepresentation.getHashIterations()" is null
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.RepresentationToModel.convertDeprecatedCredentialsFormat(RepresentationToModel.java:225)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.RepresentationToModel.createCredentials(RepresentationToModel.java:734)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UsersResource.createUser(UsersResource.java:171)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UsersResource$quarkusrestinvoker$createUser_4d0cc20e069446c6d13766369a6d45d05b869eef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```